# Wordpress запрос к users с поиском и выводом только подписчиков

Tags: wordpress, запрос, search

Доброго, дня!

Не могу сообразить, как сделать запрос:

```
$start_from = something;
$results_per_page = something;

$nameinput= '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($searchinput) . '%';
$emailinput= '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($codeinput) . '%';

$users= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM hp_users WHERE display_name like %s OR user_email like %s ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start_from,$results_per_page", $nameinput, $emailinput));
```

Здесь все понятно. Но теперь мне нужно, чтобы эти юзеры еще были и подписчики. И вот тут совсем запуталась с JOIN и прочим.

Буду рада помощи.

Comment: А что значит - "были еще и подписчики"? То есть, роль у него Подписчик, а не Администратор, скажем?

Comment: да. в этом и загвоздка. нужны только подписчики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще сделать через функцию WordPress.

```
$blogusers = get_users('search=*$name_input*&role=subscriber');
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    if ((strpos($user->user_email, $email_input) !== false) {
        echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li>';
    }
}
```